# How to create / update 2 objects [Django Rest Framework]

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, django-rest-viewsets

I'm new to django rest framework and I'm trying to create / update 2 objects in the same request:

```
class PessoaSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    user = UserSerializer(required=False)

    class Meta:
        model = Pessoa
        fields = ('id', 'user', 'nome', 'email', 'cargo', 'fone', 'cep', 'celular', 'endereco', 'observacao', 'municipio')

    def create(self, validated_data):

        usuario = User()
        usuario.first_name = validated_data.get('nome')
        usuario.username = validated_data.get('email')
        usuario.last_name = validated_data.get('nome') #TODO
        usuario.email = validated_data.get('email')
        usuario.is_active = True
        usuario.is_staff = False
        usuario.is_superuser = False
        usuario.set_password(validated_data.get('email')) #TODO
        usuario.last_login = datetime.datetime.now()
        usuario.date_joined = datetime.datetime.now()
        usuario.save()

        validated_data['user'] = usuario

        return Pessoa.objects.create(**validated_data)

    def update(self, instance, validated_data):
       #TODO
```

This is the best way to to it? Or I'm missing something?

Comment: why you need to create two objects? what exactly you need to do? I think `User.username` is `unique` field.

Comment: In this particular case, When I create a Pessoa object I need to vinculate/create a User object too:
`
    usuario.save()
    
    validated_data['user'] = usuario
`
So, I save the User object and put It into the validated_data

Comment: did it worked for u?

Comment: Yes. I was able to save the User object and link it to Pessoa Object. 

That's why I'm questioning: this is the best way/moment to do It?
In the Serializer?

Comment: I have an another method, but I think my method just same way.. just a little different..

Comment: Also In the serializer?

Comment: yes... inside it..

Comment: Ok... I another case, I need to validate some data that are coming. The best place to validate this data and redirect Is in the view?

Comment: Do your Pessoa Model inherit from User?

Comment: I really want to thank everyone who has helped so far. But I changed the whole model. I still have several doubts about how to continue development.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try below code:

```
def create(self, validated_data):
    user_data = validated_data.pop('user')
    pessoa = Pessoa.objects.create(**validated_data)
    pessoa.user.add(user_data)
    return pessoa
```